# Decorator Design Pattern in c++

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I wrote a version of decorator pattern in c++ as I wasn't able to find any good source of decorator pattern implementation in C++. I want to know if I implemented it correctly. Here is the code-

```
//implementing the pizza example in c++

#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

class Pizza{
protected:
    string description = "";
    int cost = 0;
public:
    string getdescription(){
        return description;
    }
    int getcost(){
        return cost;
    }
};
//pizzas
class PeppyPaneer: public Pizza{
public:
    PeppyPaneer(){
        cost = 100;
        description = description + " PeppyPaneer";
    }
};
class Magharita: public Pizza{
public:
    Magharita(){
        cost = 200;
        description = description + " Magharita";
    }
};

//toppings
class Barbeque: public Pizza{
public:
    Barbeque(Pizza *pizza){
        cost = pizza->getcost() + 50;
        description = pizza->getdescription()+ " Barbeque";
    }
};

class Paneer: public Pizza{
public:
    Paneer(Pizza *pizza){
        cost = pizza->getcost() + 60;
        description = pizza->getdescription() + " Paneer";
    }
};


int main(){

    Pizza *pizza = new PeppyPaneer();
    cout << pizza->getcost() << " " << pizza->getdescription() << "\n";

    pizza = new Barbeque(pizza);
    cout << pizza->getcost() << " " << pizza->getdescription() << "\n"; 

    pizza = new Paneer(pizza);
    cout << pizza->getcost() << " " << pizza->getdescription() << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inheritance is not the same as a decorator.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some comments on your code and design.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `std::string` which means that it should `#include <string>`.  It also needs `#include <iostream>`.

### Don't `#include` headers that aren't needed

The inverse of the advice above is to not include header files that are not needed.  In this case, `"bits/stdc++.h"` should be removed.  It's not standard and will only [increase compilation times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c), so you should probably avoid it in favor of using the standard `#include`s as actually needed.

### Don't leak memory

Each time your code in `main` creates a `new` pizza, it loses any pointer to the old one, making it a certainty that memory is leaked.  There are two ways to deal with that.  One is to use `delete` to match each `new`.  Another alternative is to use *smart pointers* instead.

### C++ isn't Java

Code like this looks more like Java than idiomatic C++:

```
std::string getdescription(){
    return description;
}
int getcost(){
    return cost;
}
```

Instead of writing generic getters and setters in the Java style, write idiomatic C++ instead:

```
std::string desc() const {
    return m_description;
}
int cost() const {
    return m_cost;
}
```

Here I've used a relatively common idiom of prefixing class variables with `m_` and omitting the word `get`.  Additionally, both functions are declared `const` because they do not alter the underlying object.

### Reread the decorator pattern description

I don't think your code actually faithfully implements the decorator pattern. Consider instead a revision to your pizza model in which a new pizza retains a reference to the underlying basic pizza model passed to the constructor.  That would be a better potential illustration for the use of a decorator pattern.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern for more details.